# Song 1 by Mr Physicson

Tags: wordplay, music

Mr Physicson has a good day in his lab today, so he went back home a bit tired but in joy in the afternoon. His little son wanted him to sing a song, so Mr Physicson gladly started chanting:

> *A quintet of primates, with a size less than the arbitrary reader's conception of average, were performing movements rich in oscillations on the perennial photosynthetic eykaryote,*
>
> *also causing provocation on the local lizard apex predator on terms of being able to secure its sustenance in the form of themselves...repeatedly, as the poetic structure demands.*
>
> *What was unexpected was the latter's utilization of stealth, especially concerning acoustics,*
>
> *and thus responded to the provocation by succeeding in separation of one of the former from its mentioned habitat.*

Of course, we all know Mr Physicson get a bit too science-y at times. **Can you figure the song out?**

---

Some backstory:
I encountered a similar riddle, in my own language, in the board game Mindtrap. It is not the hardest type of puzzle, but I found it hilarious! What I don't know, and had to guess, about this, is if the song is popular (it should be) and if -son is a pretty common English name suffix. I googled as much as I could to get these correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a 'scienced-up' version of:

> The nursery rhyme **Five little monkeys swinging in a tree**!

*A quintet of primates, with a size less than the arbitrary reader's conception of average, were performing movements rich in oscillations on the perennial photosynthetic eykaryote,*

> "*Five little monkeys swinging in a tree...*

*also causing provocation on the local lizard apex predator on terms of being able to secure its sustenance in the form of themselves...repeatedly, as the poetic structure demands.*

> *Teasing Mr. Crocodile: "You can't catch me!"...*

*What was unexpected was the latter's utilization of stealth, especially concerning acoustics,*

> *...along comes Mr. Crocodile as quiet as can be...*

*and thus responded to the provocation by succeeding in separation of one of the former from its mentioned habitat.*

> *...aaaaand **SNAP**!"*

Phrase by phrase:

> A quintet (**FIVE**) of primates (**MONKEYS**), with a size less than the arbitrary reader's conception of average (**LITTLE**), were performing movements rich in oscillations (**SWINGING**) on the perennial photosynthetic eykaryote (**IN THE TREE**),
>
>  also causing provocation (**TEASING**) on the local lizard apex predator (**MR. CROCODILE**) on terms of being able to secure its sustenance in the form of themselves... (**"YOU CAN'T CATCH ME!"**) repeatedly, as the poetic structure demands. (*THE SONG REPEATS WITH DECREASING NUMBER OF MONKEYS EACH TIME...*)
>
>  What was unexpected was the latter's utilization of stealth, especially concerning acoustics, (**ALONG COMES MR. CROCODILE, AS QUIET AS CAN BE**)
>
>  and thus responded to the provocation by succeeding in separation of one of the former from its mentioned habitat. (**AAAAAND SNAP!** *HE PULLS THE MONKEY OUT OF THE TREE!*)

[Here](https://kcls.org/content/five-little-monkeys-sitting-in-a-tree/) is a web page showing the lyrics and video if you want to experience the SHEER DRAMA of how it all pans out!

Comment: Correct, of course. Thanks for the edit, detailed reply and the link! `SHEER DRAMA` lol!

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis You're welcome! The funny thing was that this song came to mind almost immediately but [a different version of it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0NHrFNZWh0) (YouTube) - took me a few minutes to get that out of my head so I could remember this one!